# Can I use 'solely' with 'and'?

Tags: word-usage

Is the following sentence correct?

***His selection was based solely on his grades and extra-curricular activities***

(The context here is that I want to emphasize that this person was selected in a fair manner i.e. on the basis of grades and extra curricular activities alone.)

I'm confused because I do not know if I can write multiple reasons for selection if I've used solely.

I've looked at the definition of solely in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/solely) :
1. without another
2.to the exclusion of all else

So by definition 2, I think my sentence would be correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The sentence is fine.

Comment: If used to counter an accusation of favouritism, I'd choose this version. 'Solely' is a strong way of discounting say backhanders and nepotism. But if there is an accusation that other factors _should_ have been taken into account, I'd use 'on just two criteria'. // Your explanatory comment needs to be part of the 'question'.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is grammatically okay but places a burden on the reader to group the two criteria.  In the case of the example, grades and extra-curricular activities cover a lot of territory.  What's excluded?

It would be better to replace "solely on" with "on two criteria:"

Comment: the context is that this person was selected in a fair manner i.e. on the basis of his grades and extra curricular activities, and not because of any other reason

Comment: You need to emphasise the smallness of the number of criteria involved with say 'on just two ...'. / I'm reminded of the Monty Python _Spanish Inquisition_ sketch: 'Our chief weapon is surprise ... surprise and fear ... fear and surprise.... Our two weapons are fear and surprise ... and ruthless efficiency.... Our *three* weapons ...

Comment: "based entirely on" might work as well, rather than "based solely on".  It makes it clear that these two criteria were the only ones used.

Comment: I don't like "based entirely on" as well as "based solely on."  Also, "on two criteria" is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that definition #2 covers your case. I don't have an example at hand but have seen that usage both in fiction and in technical papers.